# How to decrease the height of the drawer layout android?

Tags: android

In my application I'm using `navigation drawer`. I want to decrease the height of the drawer. please help me.

**XML**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/r1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/background">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/logo"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"></FrameLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:divider="#FFFFFF"
        android:dividerHeight="4px"
        android:background="#1e365a"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

It totally covers the complete height of the screen. And even the drawer icon is not showing after it is clicked.

Comment: You're using ToolBar, the Button gets hid behind the drawer when it is open.

Comment: so,,,shall i remove tool bar?

Comment: What do you want in your application basically? You can also use `DrawerLayout` for that.

Comment: in my application  header  have navagation drawer icon , middle logo, right side one another image. after that header it have view pager with pagetabstrip.

Comment: OK, try giving static height to the ListView, something like: `android:layout_height="150dp"` and see if anything changes.

Comment: no it is not working, the height decreased from bottom of the layout. not from the top.

Comment: Then do it to the FrameLayout, that should work.